# Allocator usage in C++ (STL Tree)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, allocator

I've recently been trying to understand how c++ allocators work, and I've been looking to the implementation of the red-black tree that the STL library uses for things like `std::set` or `std::map`, but there are some things that I can't get my head around.

The first thing that does is convert the allocator from the type the container has to store - `_Val` - to the type of the node that the tree uses - `_Rb_tree_node<_Val>` - using the rebind template:

```
typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
    rebind<_Rb_tree_node<_Val> >::other _Node_allocator;

typedef __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Node_allocator> _Alloc_traits;
```

This I can sort out.

Now, when an element is inserted and it needs to create a new node what it does is this

```
_Node_type __node = _Alloc_traits::allocate(_M_get_Node_allocator(), 1);
```

which I assume allocates space for a single node. But then it does this

```
::new(__node) _Rb_tree_node<_Val>;
```

which I really don't know what it does, since the space for `__node` has already been allocated. But after that it also does this

```
_Alloc_traits::construct(_M_get_Node_allocator(), __node->_M_valptr(), ...);
```

which makes me even more confused, because is supposedly constructing a node (is the node allocator), but it passes the pointer `__node->_M_valptr()` which is of type `_Val*`.

If someone could explain this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The `operator new` does not allocate memory, it creates an object (and sometimes also allocate memory, but not in your case). So, I'd say the second line (`::new(__node) _Rb_tree_node<_Val>;`) probably constructs the node in the `__node` allocated memory block

Comment: Ok, but why pass the pointer `__node` to the operator? Furthermore, if it does construct the node, what does the `::construct()` do afterwards?

Comment: "why pass the pointer"? As answers explain, this is the _placement `new`_ syntax. And how else would it know where to _place_ the _`new`_ object?

Comment: @Mehlins: The `new` keyword in normal usage does two things: it allocates memory, and then it calls the `operator new` function and passes it a pointer to the memory, and this function uses the constructor to create the object at that location in memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
::new(__node) _Rb_tree_node<_Val>;
```

This form of [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) is called 'placement new'. It does not allocate new memory, but only constructs an object in the memory region pointed by the argument. Here `__node` is a pointer to already allocated memory for the node, this expression constructs an object of type `_Rb_tree_node<_Val>` in this place.

```
_Alloc_traits::construct(_M_get_Node_allocator(), __node->_M_valptr(), ...);
```

this line [constructs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) an object of type `_Val` in the memory pointed to by `__node->_M_valptr()`.

Comment: Thanks. Just the final thing. Why it uses the node allocator for `_M_valptr()`, which is of another type?

Comment: @Mehlins what is the type of `_M_valptr`?

Comment: `Val*`. The code is:
`__gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<_Val> _M_storage;
 _Val*  _M_valptr() { return _M_storage._M_ptr(); }`

Comment: @Mehlins As Ami Tavory already explained, in turn calls the [`construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) method of the allocator, which then calls placement new. (this line does not allocate any memory, it only constructs an object, so it is not using the allocator to allocate anything anyway, and thus the type of the allocator does not matter)

Comment: By the way, `construct` method in the `allocator` / `allocator_traits` is declared deprecated in C++17.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. The construct function is actually a template and uses type inference for the `_M_valptr()`. Also, the `construct` function is only deprecated for `allocator`. From what I've been seeing they're trying to shift everything to `allocator_traits`, to make things more generic. Thanks

Comment: @Mehlins Yes, I stay corrected, it is not deprecated in the `allocator_traits`. And the idea of deprecation is that the allocator should take case of allocating memory only, it does not need to know much about the type and how to construct it.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
::new(__node) _Rb_tree_node<_Val>;
```

uses [placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which simply constructs an object of type `_Rb_tree_node<_Val>` at given memory address `__node)`. This constructs the node object.

Now it needs to do something with one of the members at `_M_valptr()`. The line

```
_Alloc_traits::construct(_M_get_Node_allocator(), __node->_M_valptr(), ...);
```

(indirectly calls) the allocator's [`construct` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) which is very similar to the global placement `new` (in fact, it typically just calls it). As such, it again takes a pointer to the location where to construct the object. This constructs the value object.

Comment: Ok, so I assume it uses the placement `new` because it has no value to pass (required in the `::construct()`), and then it uses the `::construct()` function because it actually has some value to pass (hidden in the `...`).
There's one thing I still don't get. Why it uses the node allocator for `_M_valptr()`, which is of another type?

Comment: @Mehlins This really depends on the exact standard library *implementation* you're using, but, again, it's almost positively just indirectly calling the global placement new. How does it know to call the appropriate one via the node allocator? through the `rebind` mechanism you mentioned, through function templates, etc. It's not fundamentally using the node allocator, despite the apperance.

Answer (score 2):

It's using something called "[Placement New](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)", which allows an object to be constructed in memory that has already been allocated.

```
void * mem = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
MyStruct * my_struct_ptr = new(mem) MyStruct(/*Args...*/);

/*Do stuff...*/

my_struct_ptr->~MyStruct();//Literally one of the only times a good programmer would ever do this!
free(mem);
```

Or you could write it like this:

```
char * mem = new char[sizeof(MyStruct)];
MyStruct * my_struct_ptr = new(mem) MyStruct(/*Args...*/);

/*Do stuff...*/

my_struct_ptr->~MyStruct();//Literally one of the only times a good programmer would ever do this!
delete mem;
```

Or this:

```
char mem[sizeof(MyStruct)];
MyStruct * my_struct_ptr = new(mem) MyStruct(/*Args...*/);

/*Do stuff...*/

my_struct_ptr->~MyStruct();//Literally one of the only times a good programmer would ever do this!
```

The basic idea is that you now become responsible for the manual cleanup normally automatically handled by the language and compiler. Which is extremely bad practice **EXCEPT** when working with allocators, where direct control over the memory allocations becomes essential to writing a good allocator.